# Tailwind CSS: add pattern for important classnames to safelist

Tags: tailwind-css

Is it possible to create `safelist` based on [pattern](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#using-regular-expressions) with normal and **important** classnames, similar like we can add `variants`?

For example **tailwind.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './pages/**/*.{html,js}',
    './components/**/*.{html,js}',
  ],
  safelist: [
    'text-2xl',
    'text-3xl',
    {
      pattern: /bg-(red|green|blue)-(100|200|300)/,
      variants: ['!'], // IT DOES NOT WORK
    },
  ],
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible. The exclamation mark prefix would be part of the pattern:

```js
{
  pattern: /^!?bg-(red|green|blue)-(100|200|300)$/,
}
```

This would produce both `bg-red-100` as well as `!bg-red-100`, et al. See it working in [this Tailwind Play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/ddQupQYUUP?file=config) (open the *Generated CSS* panel to see the results).